# Reference variable with new name in same function

Tags: c#, reference

Is it possible to reference an existing variable using a different name to identify it.  The reason I would like to do this is to clean up my code...

### Example

Currently I have to do something like the example below...

```
private void Main()
{
    MyComplexObjectClass myComplicatedObject = new MyComplexObjectClass();
    myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2.subobj3 = "test start";

    TestFunction(ref myComplicatedObject);
}

private void TestFunction(ref myComplicatedObject)
{
    myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2.subobj3 = "test 1";
    //tons more code
    myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2.subobj3 = "test 2";
    //tons more code
    myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2.subobj3 = "test 3";
}
```

I would much rather make it more clean like the example below.  The issue is when I do this then come out of the function the referenced `myComplicatedObject` does not have a subobj3 set to "test 3" it's "test start" instead (the starting value).  I'm sure this is because the object I'm creating `subobj3` is a NEW object and not one that references the existing one.  How can I make it work?

```
private void TestFunction(ref myComplicatedObject)
{
    MySubObjectClass subobj3 = myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2.subobj3;
    subobj3 = "test 1";
    subobj3 = "test 2";
    subobj3 = "test 3";
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have `.subobj3` at the end of this line: `MySubObjectClass subobj3 = myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2;`? Seems like you did.

Comment: Opps!  Good eye.  Thanks.  ;)

Comment: I just love people who downvote questions with absolutely NO comment as to why it's a "BAD" question.  You should be ashamed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this if the thing you're assigning to the temp variable is a reference type (an instance of a `class`, not a `struct` or a primitive).

The key is that in order for it to work, you still have to be assigning to a *property* on the new variable, so the piece you "break off" to store in a variable needs to come from one level higher up (`subobj2`).

If you assign directly to the new variable (like you're doing in the second code snippet in your question), you will just be overwriting the variable within your method and nowhere else.

Try this:

```
private void TestFunction(ref myComplicatedObject)
{
    MySubObjectClass subobj2 = myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2;
    subobj2.subobj3 = "test 1";
    subobj2.subobj3 = "test 2";
    subobj2.subobj3 = "test 3";
}
```

FYI there's no need for `myComplicatedObject` to be a `ref` parameter here. You should remove the `ref`.

Comment: Yes there does need to be a `ref` keyword added like I have it.  I need to have `myComplicatedObject.subobj.subobj2.subobj3` = "test 3" and it I remove the `ref` keyword the results would be "test start" instead of what I want "test 3".

Comment: Interesting...  I will give this a try and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: @ArvoBowen I am 99% sure you don't need `ref` there, unless `MyComplexObjectClass` is not actually a `class` but rather a `struct`. Working example: https://ideone.com/sY1FGS

Comment: You might be right possibly...  I ALWAYS use that keyword when I expect to alter the value of the passed in object.  I "think" maybe you don't need it on User Defined Objects such as my complicated class.  If you were passing in an int or a string I think you would need to use the `ref` keyword in order to see the changes.  I have done it for old languages back in the day and have always had the same practice since.  Either way my way still works too.  hehe  Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: As far as the answer goes you were right on the money!  It works just like you said and all I need to do is stay away from the last leg and use one higher level.  It's not exactly what I was hoping to accomplish but it does make things look cleaner.  ;)  Thanks again!

Comment: @ArvoBowen Yes, if you were passing a primitive type (like an `int`), you would need `ref` in order to modify it and have the changes reflected in the calling method. But even with that, most of the time there are better ways to go about things. I would say overuse of `ref` is something to be avoided ([link](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/CSHARP/Too+many+%27ref%27+parameters)) and I think at least you should pin down how `ref` works so you understand when it's not serving any purpose at all. For me, I think I've used `ref` about twice in the course of 9 years writing C#.

Comment: I understand how it works and I feel like I don't use the keyword the "incorrect" way. The keyword is used to pass the variable is as a reference instead of a value. Coming from vb6 (Object-Based) it was mandatory. With c# being Object-Oriented you have the option of using it or not on "objects". I still use it to make VERY clear that I expect something in my class/object to change when it comes out of my function. In the ex link you provided that was explaining not to use the ref keyword when expecting to not change them in the function. Either way, moot point? I care more about the downvote.

Comment: @ArvoBowen Ok, I'm not the person who downvoted you.

Comment: I know, you have been nothing but help!  Thanks again.